# Overload function for rvalue and lvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Assume I have some templated class

```
template <typename T>
struct Dummy {
    // ...
};
```

And I want to overload a function 'foo' such that it accepts a lvalue
or rvalue reference of it.  I can do this using some `IsDummy` trait
as follows:

```
template <typename A>
std::enable_if<IsDummy<A>::value, void>
foo(A &&dummy)
{
    // ....
}
```

IIRC in some C++11 draft it was legal that

```
template <typename A>
foo(Dummy<A> &&dummy)
{
    // ....
}
```

would accept both, lvalue- and value- references.

Now my questions:

- a) Is it correct that it was allowed in some draft?
- b) Why was this feature/bug removed?  I think I read somewhere that it was due to a conflict with "concepts".

However, I can't find appropriate references for this any more. Does somebody have a better memory or bookmarks?

Comment: I dug through the mailing lists of the C++ committee, and found out that the two features were roughly added at the same time by the same authors, as they were considered tightly coupled problems. See [N1377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm) and [N1385](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm). As such, I don't think a) is true.

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean to say "added" but "proposed", but oh well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a) Is it correct that it was allowed in some draft?

Yes, it was allowed in what is known as "rvalue references 1.0" (see [N2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html)).

> b) Why was this feature/bug removed? I think I read somewhere that it was due to a conflict with "concepts".

It was removed because binding an rvalue reference to an lvalue could lead to a violation of the "Principle of Type-safe Overloading" in the presence of Concepts:

> Every function must be type-safe in isolation, without regard to how it has been overloaded.

For example, if we define the following overloads:

```
template< CopyConstructible T > void f( T const & t ); // #1
template< MoveConstructible T > void f( T && t );      // #2
```

Then calling `f` with a copyable lvalue would select #1.  However, if T is a non-copyable type (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) then #1 is not a viable overload so the compiler must select #2, possibly stealing resources from an lvalue without warning.

See "rvalue references 2.0" ([N2844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2844.html)) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Having the info from Andrew's answer I also found some very [readable article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx) on the subject (rvalue-/lvalue-references), which also gives references to how things evolved in this matter.

Comment: Just be aware that the article is based entirely on "rvalue references 1.0" and includes examples of binding rvalue references to lvalues.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) for a more up to date article by the same author.

Comment: Sure, but finding information about the final standard is not the problem.  Such "historical notes" about "value references 1.0" were exactly what I was looking (and asking) for.  And it actually seems that most people have forgotten that they ever existed (as the deleted answers to my question would prove).  In my opinion understanding the evolution process of the C++11 standard is important and interesting.